# Loading foreach using core methods in ZK MVVM

Tags: zk

I would like to read some values from my vm. Here's an example of what I've done so far

```
<div forEach="${vm.activityData.activityList}">
    <label
        value="@load(c:cat3('vm.activitiData.', each, '.organizer' ))" />
</div>
```

But it seems like it is unable to read the `each` inside the `cat3`. My objective is to get the organizer for each activity.  Any idea how to achieve this ?

---

### Update

For example, I want to simplify from this codes :

```
<div>
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.A.name)" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.ASponsor)" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.AOrganizer)" />
    <separator/>
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.B.name)" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.BSponsor)" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData.BOrganizer)" />
    <separator/>
</div>
```

into

```
<div forEach="${vm.activityData.activityList}">
    <label value="@load(c:cat3('vm.activityData.', each, '.name'))" />
    <label value="@load(c:cat3('vm.activityData.', each, 'Sponsor'))" />
    <label value="@load(c:cat3('vm.activityData.', each, 'Organizer'))" />
    <separator/>
</div>
```

Basically what I want to do is to dynamically combine part of strings into one string. And then use `@load(string)`.

Comment: It seems like a dynamic variable is not possible. Is there any other way to handle this situation ?

Comment: why don't you do `forEach="@load(vm.activityData.activityList)"`?

Comment: @chillworld yes, that things work, but sometimes i might use `vm.activityData.eachAny` instead of `vm.activityData.each.Any`.

Comment: oh ait, you want to load vm.activitiData.each.organizer  And each stands for the value of the getter/setter?

Comment: @chillworld I've updated the post. If it's impossible, then I might reconsider to reconstruct back all the java classes.

Comment: `try : @load(vm.activityData[each].name)`

Comment: @chillworld I guess it didnt work. By the way, my zk version is 7.0.0,i dont know if it is working on latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I had the time to test it and I prepared a fiddle for you.
Your ZK version is good but I did forget to add one more thing.
You have to make use of the `custom-attributes` otherwise it wouldn't work.

Solution :

```
<div forEach="${vm.activityData.activityList}">
    <custom-attributes field="${each}"/>
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData[field].name)" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData[c:cat(field, 'Sponsor')]" />
    <label value="@load(vm.activityData[c:cat(field, 'Organizer')]" />
    <separator/>
</div>
```

I created fast a [working fiddle where you can test or look how it works](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/35k3jh8/1-generic-calling-of-property).

Comment: hey its working thx.. I guess `<custom-attributes>` is a new stuff for me.. I'll try to play around with it

Comment: try also searching for `@ref` this is also a great annotation what reduces the calling of getters.